# Javascript ,classes to add constructor-function

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I'm kinda new with js + ES6 + class; I have problem with creating function inside constructor.

```
#1. I need to add new Hobby, a person allowed to have plenty hobbies ;
#2. I don't know how to show all the data of students;
```

another questions are in the `comments` ,in case if you want to answer it too, if not i'm also fine.
so here's my code :

```
class Student {
  constructor(name,hobbies){

    this.name = name;

    var hobby = new Set(); //do I set here or inside the function ??
 //since the function addHobbies also need, then it's fine to be global right ?


    this.hobbies = (hobbies) => {    //function ES6 like this right ??

      this.hobbies = hobby.add(hobbies);

      return this.hobbies;  //can I return hobby instead of this.hobbies ??
    };
  }
  setName(newName){
    this.name = newName;
  }

  addHobbies(newHobbies){
    this.Hobbies = hobby.add(newHobbies); //it should be like this to add >> to set ?
  }


  getName(){
    return this.name;
  }

  getHobbies(){
    return this.hobbies;
  }
}
```

and how to return all the data ?

```
let andy = new Student("andy","dance");
let vince = new Student("vince","codding");
```

so it will show all students-attribute by `getCode()` ?

Comment: `return this.hobbies` will simply return the function, so that doesn't make sense to do. `hobby.add(newHobbies);` won't work since `hobby` doesn't exist in that scope.

Comment: @FelixKling well I did try to declare hobby inside function before this, didnt work like i want tho.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Student {
  constructor(name, hobbies) {
    this.name = name;

    // Allow passing both an array of hobbies and a single hobby
    this.hobbies = Array.isArray(hobbies) ? new Set(hobbies) : new Set([hobbies]);
  }

  setName(newName) {
    this.name = newName;
  }

  addHobbies(newHobbies) {
      if (Array.isArray(newHobbies)) {
          newHobbies.forEach((hobby) => this.hobbies.add(hobby));
      } else {
          this.hobbies.add(newHobbies);
      }
  }

  getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  getHobbies() {
    return this.hobbies;
  }
}

let andy = new Student("andy","dancing");
let vince = new Student("vince",["codding", "running"]);
andy.addHobbies("slipping");
vince.addHobbies(["running", "eating"]);
```

Comment: This is JavaScript. There is no `private` keyword or any member declarations.

Comment: Only one thing is it is better to have one type for `this.hobbies`. I mean in constructor you have to create an array of one element or even a Set to have them unique

Comment: @Bergi You're right, I use TypeScript myself and took it from there. I revised my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> do I set here or inside the function ??

That depends on what you need. Do you want each `Student` instead to have one set of hobbies, or do you want to create a new set every time the function is called?

> ```
> this.hobbies = (hobbies) => {    //function ES6 like this right ??
>     this.hobbies = hobby.add(hobbies);
> ```

That doesn't work at all. You're creating the property with a function value, but when the method is called you're overwriting the property with the return value of the [`add` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/add).

---

To make it work, I'd recommend making the `.hobbies` set an [instance property instead of a local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13418669/1048572?javascript-do-i-need-to-put-this-var-for-every-variable-in-an-object).

```
class Student {
  constructor(name, ...hobbies) {
    this.name = name;
    this.hobbies = new Set();
    this.addHobbies(...hobbies);
  }

  getName() {
    return this.name;
  }
  setName(newName) {
    this.name = newName;
  }

  getHobbies() {
    return this.hobbies;
  }
  addHobbies(...newHobbies) {
    for (const newHobby of newHobbies)
      this.hobbies.add(newHobby);
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you insist on using a local constructor variable, it would look like this:

```
class Student {
  constructor(name, ...hobbies) {
    this.name = name;
    this.hobbies = new Set(...hobbies);

    this.getHobbies = () => {
      return this.hobbies;
    };
    this.addHobbies = (...newHobbies) => {
      for (const newHobby of newHobbies)
        this.hobbies.add(newHobby);
    };
  }

  … // further methods (for name etc)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are in the correct direction. I have rewritten your class to do what I think is more similar to what you are trying to achieve.

Play with the code at: https://jsbin.com/vejumo/edit?js,console

And here's the rewritten class:

```
class Student {
  constructor(name, hobbies = []){

    this.name = name;

    // new Set() is used to work with objects. It does not work with well with strings
    // Let's use an array to store the hobbies.
    // if a hobby or an hobbies array is passed, store it, otherwise set an empty array.
    this.hobbies = this.parseHobbies(hobbies); 
  }

  // This function will normalize the hobbies to an Array
  parseHobbies(hobbies) {
    if (typeof hobbies === "string") {
      // hobbies is a string, means it's a single hobby and not an array
      return [hobbies];
    }
    // Assuming the hobbies is a an Array
    return hobbies; 
  }

  setName(newName) {
    this.name = newName;
  }

  // this function will allow you to add a single hobby to the array
  addHobbies(hobbies = []) {
    // Same logic like in constract, this can accept a string or an array
    // We use Array.concat and push to append to array
    this.hobbies = this.hobbies.concat(this.parseHobbies(hobbies)); 
  }

  getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  getHobbies() {
    return this.hobbies
  }

  // This will return all student attributes.
  getAttributes() {
    // Return a copy of all the attributes instead of returning references
    return Object.assign({}, this);
  }
}

let george = new Student("George", "Sports");
george.addHobbies(["Singing", "Fishing"]);
george.addHobbies("Dancing");
console.log(george.getAttributes());
```